npm ci command is getting stuck during the Docker build process on AWS EC2 Jenkins server
I was following this link (https://medium.com/@kishanmadhesiya/jenkins-ci-cd-pipeline-with-github-for-deploying-react-docker-application-on-ec2-instance-9bc1d993b7c3) to set up a CI/CD pipeline for my React application on Jenkins server. I made some amendments to the code, using npm ci instead of 'yarn'. However, it always gets stuck at the npm ci step. The logs are as shown below:
Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/tbs-frontend
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential github-tbs-frontend-jenkins
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/tbs-frontend/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://yeerouhew-ncs: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@github.com/yeerouhew-ncs/nus-iss-practice-module # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://yeerouhew-ncs@github.com/yeerouhew-ncs/nus-iss-practice-module
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.34.1'
using GIT_SSH to set credentials Github, Jenkins Integration for tbs-frontend
Verifying host key using known hosts file
You're using 'Known hosts file' strategy to verify ssh host keys, but your known_hosts file does not exist, please go to 'Manage Jenkins' -> 'Security' -> 'Git Host Key Verification Configuration' and configure host key verification.
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://yeerouhew-ncs: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@github.com/yeerouhew-ncs/nus-iss-practice-module +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/main^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision e7a2f259980768cf5e32b963d681640080bfde1d (refs/remotes/origin/main)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git read-tree -mu HEAD # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f e7a2f259980768cf5e32b963d681640080bfde1d # timeout=10
Commit message: "edit Dockerfile"
 > git rev-list --no-walk e7a2f259980768cf5e32b963d681640080bfde1d # timeout=10
[tbs-frontend] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins328970621941343518.sh
+ docker buildx build -t tbs-frontend tbs-frontend
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 633B done
#1 DONE 0.1s

#2 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:20-alpine
#2 DONE 2.8s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:latest
#3 DONE 2.9s

#4 [internal] load .dockerignore
#4 transferring context: 174B done
#4 DONE 0.0s

#5 [stage-1 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:latest@sha256:6db391d1c0cfb30588ba0bf72ea999404f2764febf0f1f196acd5867ac7efa7e
#5 resolve docker.io/library/nginx:latest@sha256:6db391d1c0cfb30588ba0bf72ea999404f2764febf0f1f196acd5867ac7efa7e 0.1s done
#5 ...

#6 [internal] load build context
#6 transferring context: 1.31MB 0.1s done
#6 DONE 0.2s

#5 [stage-1 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:latest@sha256:6db391d1c0cfb30588ba0bf72ea999404f2764febf0f1f196acd5867ac7efa7e
#5 sha256:52478f8cd6a142fd462f0a7614a7bb064e969a4c083648235d6943c786df8cc7 2.29kB / 2.29kB done
#5 sha256:6db391d1c0cfb30588ba0bf72ea999404f2764febf0f1f196acd5867ac7efa7e 9.85kB / 9.85kB done
#5 sha256:92b11f67642b62bbb98e7e49169c346b30e20cd3c1c034d31087e46924b9312e 7.02kB / 7.02kB done
#5 sha256:8a1e25ce7c4f75e372e9884f8f7b1bedcfe4a7a7d452eb4b0a1c7477c9a90345 0B / 29.12MB 0.7s
#5 sha256:e78b137be3552e1f36d84cb01c533a23febe4c48f6fcdff5d5b26a45a636053b 0B / 41.39MB 0.9s
#5 sha256:8a1e25ce7c4f75e372e9884f8f7b1bedcfe4a7a7d452eb4b0a1c7477c9a90345 13.89MB / 29.12MB 1.1s
#5 sha256:8a1e25ce7c4f75e372e9884f8f7b1bedcfe4a7a7d452eb4b0a1c7477c9a90345 22.02MB / 29.12MB 1.2s
#5 sha256:8a1e25ce7c4f75e372e9884f8f7b1bedcfe4a7a7d452eb4b0a1c7477c9a90345 29.12MB / 29.12MB 1.3s
#5 sha256:8a1e25ce7c4f75e372e9884f8f7b1bedcfe4a7a7d452eb4b0a1c7477c9a90345 29.12MB / 29.12MB 1.3s done
#5 sha256:e78b137be3552e1f36d84cb01c533a23febe4c48f6fcdff5d5b26a45a636053b 2.10MB / 41.39MB 1.4s
#5 sha256:e78b137be3552e1f36d84cb01c533a23febe4c48f6fcdff5d5b26a45a636053b 5.24MB / 41.39MB 1.5s
#5 sha256:39fc875bd2b2e4f867e8e5cc5ad43bd5d6650ddeaf8c28b04f374f7fbca085f3 0B / 624B 1.5s
#5 sha256:e78b137be3552e1f36d84cb01c533a23febe4c48f6fcdff5d5b26a45a636053b 14.68MB / 41.39MB 1.7s
#5 extracting sha256:8a1e25ce7c4f75e372e9884f8f7b1bedcfe4a7a7d452eb4b0a1c7477c9a90345
#5 sha256:e78b137be3552e1f36d84cb01c533a23febe4c48f6fcdff5d5b26a45a636053b 23.07MB / 41.39MB 1.9s
#5 sha256:39fc875bd2b2e4f867e8e5cc5ad43bd5d6650ddeaf8c28b04f374f7fbca085f3 624B / 624B 1.9s done
#5 sha256:e78b137be3552e1f36d84cb01c533a23febe4c48f6fcdff5d5b26a45a636053b 28.31MB / 41.39MB 2.0s
#5 sha256:035788421403127b57e688a82706198331f06545a955b526f89f2bf53f52b078 0B / 954B 2.0s
#5 sha256:e78b137be3552e1f36d84cb01c533a23febe4c48f6fcdff5d5b26a45a636053b 41.39MB / 41.39MB 2.2s
#5 sha256:035788421403127b57e688a82706198331f06545a955b526f89f2bf53f52b078 954B / 954B 2.3s
#5 sha256:e78b137be3552e1f36d84cb01c533a23febe4c48f6fcdff5d5b26a45a636053b 41.39MB / 41.39MB 2.3s done
#5 sha256:035788421403127b57e688a82706198331f06545a955b526f89f2bf53f52b078 954B / 954B 2.3s done
#5 sha256:87c3fb37cbf2f763f67f3b270aa0785ca05a2caedac399b4bfeedfd0ccd77d87 0B / 392B 2.4s
#5 sha256:c5cdd1ce752da415a6563d9432e1ee718b2f4ba353ee2bb7c8ce2aa78d5b4ee1 0B / 1.21kB 2.4s
#5 sha256:33952c5995320e59a81112f411bfb02e097562a72c12e85828da51132ace47cd 0B / 1.40kB 2.4s
#5 sha256:c5cdd1ce752da415a6563d9432e1ee718b2f4ba353ee2bb7c8ce2aa78d5b4ee1 1.21kB / 1.21kB 2.6s done
#5 sha256:33952c5995320e59a81112f411bfb02e097562a72c12e85828da51132ace47cd 1.40kB / 1.40kB 2.6s done
#5 sha256:87c3fb37cbf2f763f67f3b270aa0785ca05a2caedac399b4bfeedfd0ccd77d87 392B / 392B 2.9s done
#5 extracting sha256:8a1e25ce7c4f75e372e9884f8f7b1bedcfe4a7a7d452eb4b0a1c7477c9a90345 4.0s done
#5 extracting sha256:e78b137be3552e1f36d84cb01c533a23febe4c48f6fcdff5d5b26a45a636053b
#5 ...

#7 [build 1/7] FROM docker.io/library/node:20-alpine@sha256:ef3f47741e161900ddd07addcaca7e76534a9205e4cd73b2ed091ba339004a75
#7 resolve docker.io/library/node:20-alpine@sha256:ef3f47741e161900ddd07addcaca7e76534a9205e4cd73b2ed091ba339004a75 0.0s done
#7 sha256:73753e08a8755a0838696135be60a5f1e33c6cf92a15bc4e71465f3d0fda6422 1.16kB / 1.16kB done
#7 sha256:09c27ad02af8a1416d21c72ed2428dcfc10d86e9ad0f7234c7d876fab740c7d6 7.14kB / 7.14kB done
#7 sha256:4abcf20661432fb2d719aaf90656f55c287f8ca915dc1c92ec14ff61e67fbaf8 3.41MB / 3.41MB 0.4s done
#7 sha256:e5682cd217711ef874f1e9e97a15da5cf88aee99e69f49d8024b90c10f70cffb 42.20MB / 42.20MB 2.2s done
#7 sha256:ed63b364a3a06c54b73ccb4609a8aadc9b00cc76757f40d27c5a08440a196d1e 2.34MB / 2.34MB 0.7s done
#7 sha256:ef3f47741e161900ddd07addcaca7e76534a9205e4cd73b2ed091ba339004a75 1.43kB / 1.43kB done
#7 extracting sha256:4abcf20661432fb2d719aaf90656f55c287f8ca915dc1c92ec14ff61e67fbaf8 0.2s done
#7 sha256:39c48b75308248db440b30f97a8241f0fe72f599e69b59aab20eee1db478c962 448B / 448B 0.8s done
#7 extracting sha256:e5682cd217711ef874f1e9e97a15da5cf88aee99e69f49d8024b90c10f70cffb 5.8s done
#7 extracting sha256:ed63b364a3a06c54b73ccb4609a8aadc9b00cc76757f40d27c5a08440a196d1e 0.3s done
#7 extracting sha256:39c48b75308248db440b30f97a8241f0fe72f599e69b59aab20eee1db478c962 done
#7 DONE 8.7s

#5 [stage-1 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:latest@sha256:6db391d1c0cfb30588ba0bf72ea999404f2764febf0f1f196acd5867ac7efa7e
#5 ...

#8 [build 2/7] WORKDIR /app
#8 DONE 0.2s

#5 [stage-1 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:latest@sha256:6db391d1c0cfb30588ba0bf72ea999404f2764febf0f1f196acd5867ac7efa7e
#5 extracting sha256:e78b137be3552e1f36d84cb01c533a23febe4c48f6fcdff5d5b26a45a636053b 5.0s
#5 extracting sha256:e78b137be3552e1f36d84cb01c533a23febe4c48f6fcdff5d5b26a45a636053b 5.1s done
#5 extracting sha256:39fc875bd2b2e4f867e8e5cc5ad43bd5d6650ddeaf8c28b04f374f7fbca085f3
#5 extracting sha256:39fc875bd2b2e4f867e8e5cc5ad43bd5d6650ddeaf8c28b04f374f7fbca085f3 done
#5 extracting sha256:035788421403127b57e688a82706198331f06545a955b526f89f2bf53f52b078 done
#5 extracting sha256:87c3fb37cbf2f763f67f3b270aa0785ca05a2caedac399b4bfeedfd0ccd77d87 done
#5 extracting sha256:c5cdd1ce752da415a6563d9432e1ee718b2f4ba353ee2bb7c8ce2aa78d5b4ee1 done
#5 extracting sha256:33952c5995320e59a81112f411bfb02e097562a72c12e85828da51132ace47cd done
#5 DONE 11.5s

#9 [build 3/7] RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
#9 DONE 3.6s

#10 [build 4/7] COPY package*.json ./
#10 DONE 0.2s

#11 [build 5/7] RUN npm ci

My Dockerfile looks like this:
FROM node:20-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Does anybody have an experience this?
I would appreciate any help :)

You don't seem to have actually included the logs in the question.  Can you [edit] the question to include them?  (Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.)
